# mySQL mariaDB INSERT syntax error with IP adress

Tags: mysql, mariadb, syntax-error

```
INSERT INTO devices3 (`name`, `ip`, `port`, `switch`) VALUES (name, 255.255.255.255, 55555, 12);
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.255.255, 55555, 12)' at line 1.

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name   | char(25)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ip     | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| port   | int(5)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| switch | int(4)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

why is this not working?

Comment: Why are you not quoting the IP? It's of type `varchar`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem is ip address as it is a string. You have to have quotation marks around like below:

```
INSERT INTO devices3 (`name`, `ip`, `port`, `switch`) VALUES (name, '255.255.255.255', 55555, 12);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

varchar must be enclosed into quotes, `'255.255.255.255'`